# Is there any difference between "cold wave", "cold spell" and "cold snap"

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonyms

I found that those three are all frequently used as I've searched each of them in NYT site. I wonder what's the difference among them in usage.

The examples are as below.

**Cold spell**:

- Although this **cold spell** would not have been unusual before global warming, it is now a relatively rare event in any one region.
- That first **cold spell** of the season always feels especially harsh.
- How do you feel about the frigid **cold spell** gripping North America?

**Cold snap**:

- With climate change warming the Arctic air, researchers say, **cold snaps** are getting warmer. The recent spell of cold was an outlier.
- While temperatures across the country on Monday will remain below zero, the **cold snap** will start to break during the day Tuesday.
- Slippery conditions as **cold snap** ends in most of Finland

**Cold wave**

- The severest **cold wave** of this Winter is being experienced.
- More than 270 people have died from a month-old **cold wave** in northern India
- This warmth came despite a significant January **cold wave** in the eastern United States that brought copious snowfall to several regions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if all speakers use these terms in the same way, but for many speakers a **cold snap** is a sudden and abrupt drop in temperature, whereas with **cold spell** and a **cold wave** there is no implication of sudden change. A **spell** is a length of time, and a **wave** is something that comes in and grows gradually until it breaks.